# How to add background color for all the text come inside curly brackets in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using sunEditor-react to get HTML files into a text editor. I got the HTML value and displayed inside the editor successfully.

The purpose of this to edit the HTML file in the frontend.
But when I am getting the HTML template, there are some places I need to highlight and show.

I need to highlight the text inside curly brackets `{}`.
Can any explain me how can I do this using CSS or a function to highlight the values inside `{}`.

This is my current class.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import SunEditor from 'suneditor-react';

import { useLocale } from 'hooks/useLocale/useLocale';
import { Button, Heading, Loader, Typography } from 'ui/atoms';

import 'suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css';

import { useStyles } from './Edit.styles';
import { EditProps } from './Edit.types';
import { EditWarning } from './editWarning/EditWarning';

export const EMAIL_EDIT_WARNING_COOKIE_KEY = 'emailEditWarning';

export const Edit = ({ title, defaultTemplate }: EditProps) => {
 const classes = useStyles();
 const { formatMessage } = useLocale();
 const [htmlData, setHtmlData] = useState(defaultTemplate?.html);

 if (!defaultTemplate) {
   return <Loader className={classes.loader} />;
 }

 function reset() {
   setHtmlData(defaultTemplate?.html);
 } 

 return (
   <>
     <div className={classes.button}>
       <Button type="button" onClick={reset}>
         {formatMessage({ id: 'event.emails.edit.reset' })}
       </Button>
     </div>

     <div className={classes.container}>
       <Heading variant="h4" bold className={classes.title}>
         {formatMessage({ id: 'event.emails.edit.title' })}
       </Heading>
       <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.subtitle}>
         {title}
       </Typography>

       <EditWarning name={EMAIL_EDIT_WARNING_COOKIE_KEY}>
         <div>{formatMessage({ id: 'event.emails.edit.warning_message' })}</div>
         <div>{formatMessage({ id: 'event.emails.edit.warning_note' })}</div>
       </EditWarning>
     </div>
     <SunEditor
       width="100%"
       height="100%"
       autoFocus={true}
       setContents={htmlData}
 
     />
   </>
 ); };
```

I need to add css to  to highlight all the values inside curly brackets {}.

This is the current UI.
[image: UI]

Here I need to highlight `{{FULL_NAME}}` and `{{{event_name}}}`.
How can I do this using CSS or any function in react?

Can any one please give a solution for this? I am trying this more than a week to get a solution?

Comment: Is the `htmlData` in string format or actual HTML format?

Comment: @PrajwalKulkarni it's string

Answer (score 0):

I know that with regular React, adding an Inline style like this  `style={{ color: "blue" }}` to any tag would do the trick. (Note the double brackets are necessary for JSX.)

But I'm not all that familiar with sunEditor. If it lets you use a custom CSS stylesheet, you could try adding an id or className and changing color with `!important` to try and override the Atom ui framework your using.

Comment: It's not about sunEditor. Even if I want to add inline css, I only need to add those to the variables inside curly brackets. Not to the whole text.

Comment: Ok, so your saying you only want specific parts of the text styled?

Comment: I have added the complete code. Lets don't think about the sunEditor. Lets say there a paragraph inside div. That paragraph have lot of words and in the middle it have some variables inside curly brackets like {{First_name}}, {{Last_name}} etc. I only need to highlight those words

Comment: Got it. The right way to do this is wrap whatever you want changed in a ```<span>``` tag, then add the inline style to that tag.

Comment: Can't do like that, because I am getting this HTML form API.  So can't add any tag to HTML. I think the only solution is to find the variables inside {{ }} and then change those colors. But I don't know how to do that

Comment: One trick that could work is inspect the API element in your browser and it will have some of it's own ids and classNames. Grab the outermost one and in your ```index.css``` tell it to have a color with the ```!important``` indicator. Has worked for me a few times. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving the HTML data as a string, you could use the string method `replaceAll` to replace the curly braces with span elements, and then parse the string to DOM. You could then add styling to span elements in your stylesheet as you wish.

```
const [htmlData, setHtmlData] = useState(defaultTemplate?.html);

const htmlWithTags = htmlData.replaceAll('{{','<span>').replaceAll('}}','</span>') //Replace curly braces with HTML elements.

const domHTML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlWithTags, "text/xml"); //Parse string to actual DOM.
```

You can then use the `domHTML` variable data to render your HTML content.

In your stylesheet:

```
span{
 color:red;      //Change the color and weight accordingly, or add more customisations as required.
 font-weight:bold;
}
```